# How to find number of shards in sharded MongoDB cluster programatically

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-cluster

I know sh.status() command can give me shards information. However I cannot figure out, how to run this programatically using mongo java driver.

Comment: Go into the shell and type `printShardingStatus` without any parenthesis `()`. Then have fun reading. It's not just a command but a series of queries on system collections.

Comment: pretty useful. Thanks

Comment: Well I figure if you're going to want to return that information in your own program you should be able to follow the code that's already there. You can get the same information for everything in the mongo shell, which is really just a JavaScript REPL. For instance `sh.status` lead to the `printShardingStatus` function and so on.